# Library interposition nanosleep

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I am trying to hook function calls using library interposition in Linux. I am capturing a lot pretty well but there are some cases that I am missing...one of this cases is nanosleep(). The binary I am hooking sleeps the thread using this function every one second...if I use any other tool like strace I can hook the calls without the problem...what could I be missing? here is the definition I am using in the shared library...

```
int nanosleep (const struct timespec *rqtp, struct timespec *rmtp)
{
    static int (*my_nanosleep)(const struct timespec *, struct timespec *) = NULL;
    if (!my_nanosleep)
       my_nanosleep = (int(*)(const struct timespec *, struct timespec *)) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "nanosleep");
    printf("\n\n nanosleep() is called and hooked with my_nanosleep() \n\n");

    FILE *f = fopen("/home/user/Desktop/Test.txt", "a");    
        if (f==NULL)
    {
                printf("error opening file\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    char *text1 = "nanosleep()";
    fprintf(f, "%s\n", text1);
    fclose(f);  

        return(my_nanosleep(rqtp, rmtp));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. In order to be able to capture function calls I was running the application in the terminal as a root...on top of that, I was using sudo, this was the problem. I removed sudo and now I am capturing all the function calls...before it was very limited and the outcome was the same every time...

Answer (score 0):

The tool *strace* shows you only the calls through the userspace/os-boundary. So, if you see a line like

```
 nanosleep({1, 0}, 0x7ffd50e5acf0)       = 0
```

the program you are intercepting calls for might have called the glibc-function `nanosleep()` directly (which results in turn in the syscall `nanosleep()`. In this case your interception should be working as expected.

But it might also be possible, that the program calls

```
sleep(1);
```

in which case the glibc-function `sleep()` (which you did *not* intercept) invokes the `nanosleep()`-syscall. So you would have to intercept the call to `sleep()` in that case.

The tool `ltrace` can help you find out which library-functions the program you examine calls.

Comment: Actually yes, I am trying to intercept nanosleep, sleep and also usleep...maybe library interposition has some limitations with processes running in the main thread?

Comment: One interesting thing is that I am noticing that my library is intercepting a lot of systems call at the beginning of the application execution and at the end, once I send the stop signal...however, I am seeing nothing in the middle...lets say I am running the binary for 1 minute: I am seeing only systems calls happening during the first and last second of the process...once the main thread starts I got nothing but silence...